# Permission in shmget() function in C

Tags: c

I have a quick question regarding `shmget()` function in C.  The program is very simple.  It asks user to enter a shmid, and it out puts Key, Mode, Owner etc.

I am using `buffer->shm_perm.mode` to get the permission but its giving the permissions in octal form (960  etc).  Is there any way I can change it so it shows permission like "**rwx**"?

Thanks

Comment: You'd have to write the code; it isn't all that hard, but there isn't a well-known standard function to do it for you.

Comment: I *hope* that octal doesn't give you a digit `9`! Might it be hex?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I have the wholeprogram written and working.  I only want to change the above line so it gives me "rwx" instead of 960 for permission.  Permissions are correct but I need to change the formate.

Comment: 960 in decimal is octal 01700.  The information on the [`shmctl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmctl.html) page says that only the bottom nine bits (3 octal digits) of the permissions are relevant, so that would normally convert to `rwx------`.  The code in my answer would do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (non-reentrant) function to convert a `mode_t` value into a string that might be produced by `ls`:

```
/*
** Convert a mode field into "ls -l" type perms field.
*/
static char *lsperms(int mode)
{
    static char *rwx[] = {"---", "--x", "-w-", "-wx",
    "r--", "r-x", "rw-", "rwx"};
    static char bits[11];

    bits[0] = filetypeletter(mode);
    strcpy(&bits[1], rwx[(mode >> 6) & 7]);
    strcpy(&bits[4], rwx[(mode >> 3) & 7]);
    strcpy(&bits[7], rwx[(mode & 7)]);
    if (mode & S_ISUID)
        bits[3] = (mode & 0100) ? 's' : 'S';
    if (mode & S_ISGID)
        bits[6] = (mode & 0010) ? 's' : 'l';
    if (mode & S_ISVTX)
        bits[9] = (mode & 0001) ? 't' : 'T';
    bits[10] = '\0';
    return(bits);
}
```

This can be simplified for shared memory since you don't need the file type (function not provided here anyway) or the special permissions bits.

```
/*
** Convert a mode field into "ls -l" type shared memory perms field.
*/
static char *shmperms(int mode)
{
    static char *rwx[] = {"---", "--x", "-w-", "-wx",
    "r--", "r-x", "rw-", "rwx"};
    static char bits[10];

    strcpy(&bits[0], rwx[(mode >> 6) & 7]);
    strcpy(&bits[3], rwx[(mode >> 3) & 7]);
    strcpy(&bits[6], rwx[(mode & 7)]);
    bits[9] = '\0';
    return(bits);
}
```

Comment: Since the code uses `strcpy()`, the assignment of the null terminator is strictly redundant.